# Pillow doesn't install in my virtualenv environment

Tags: python, centos, pip, virtualenv, python-imaging-library

My issue is when I enter on my environment and then try to install **Pillow**, it doesn't install on my environment (*this is not a problem of dependencies like libjpeg8-dev and others package*s). However, if I try to install another library, e.g. **geopy**, it works. Kinda rare behavior.
I looked at my list of libraries with **pip list** and still I've never seen **Pillow** installed on my **venv**.
I'm running my application in a Centos 7.1 x64 machine.
I'm using Python 3.4.3, virtualenv 12.0.7, pip 8.0.0 and setuptools 12.0.5.
Oh, before I forget it. Other library that doesn't appear in my venv is psycopg2.

Please help, this is such a headache. I don't have any traceback to show you guys, because everything seems to work "normally".

Comment: question, did you try to import Pillow from the python shell? Did it give you an error?

Comment: Yes @Ale, it gives me an error. [Here's a image showing that](http://s24.postimg.org/5eraqnt2t/Screenshot_from_2016_01_20_15_46_38.png)

Comment: [Here's another image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HGRNt.png)

Comment: You should add the relevant plaintext to your question, rather than post external links. When you pip install in the activated venv, there is a lot of text as it builds components. There may be error messages in there.

Comment: @KennyOstrom this what I get for installing Pillow `Collecting Pillow
  Using cached Pillow-3.1.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: Pillow
  Running setup.py install for Pillow
Successfully installed Pillow-3.1.0
` Then I look at my libraries with `pip list` and got this `pip (8.0.0)
setuptools (12.0.5)`